# Cash flow diagram in python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I need to make a very simple image that will illustrate a cash flow diagram based on user input. Basically, I just need to make an axis and some arrows facing up and down and proportional to the value of the cash flow. I would like to know how to do this with matplot.

Comment: matplotlib, but it might be over kill

Comment: python doesn't seem like the right tool for this.

Comment: ``matplotlib``, and I don't see how is it an overkill.

Comment: Just made [a super duper app](https://gist.github.com/rgbkrk/6546847) you can use freely for this.

Answer (score 3):

The best tool can be matplotlib. You can simply store the values in a list and then use '[stem](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html)' to draw the lines. Then you can use [markers](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers) with triangle_up and triangle_down to show the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need arrows pointing up and down, use Unicode arrows like "↑" and "↓". This would be really simple if rendering in a browser.